# PostgreSQL Extract Year from Timestamp and then apply Interval Calculation

Tags: postgresql, date, intervals

I'd like to filter a dataset to include everything with a created_date >= current year plus 5 full years prior. If I ran this today, I'd want anything with a created_date >= 01/01/2016 (2021 - 5 = 2016)

```
where extract(year from created_date) >= extract(year from current_date) - interval '5 years'
```

of course this doesn't work with double precision datatype. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_trunc()` to "round" the dates to the first of January.

```
where date_trunc('year', created_date) >= date_trunc('year', current_timestamp) - interval '5 years'
```

But the "*I'd want anything with a created_date >= 01/01/2016*" seems to indicate you might want:

```
where created_date >= date_trunc('year', current_timestamp) - interval '5 years'
```